# How to tell if an error has been thrown before in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I have a function:

```
function mymodule_validate_ubercart_checkout($form, &$form_state)  
{
   $allOtherValidatorsPassed = hasAllValidated();
   if ($allOtherValidatorsPassed) 
   {
        // Only now do I do my actual check...
        if (empty($creditCardDetails)) form_set_error('myfield', 
            t('Invalid credit card details entered. Please try again.') 
        );
    } 
}
```

So basically I need to know how to do the hasAllValidated function. I just want my actual validation to happen if all other validations prior to this one has passed.

How do I do that? I can't seem to find where validation errors are stored so I can check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the **form_get_errors** function to check if the validations were success before your function.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_get_errors/7

```
function mymodule_validate_ubercart_checkout($form, &$form_state)  
{
    $allOtherValidatorsPassed = form_get_errors();
    if (empty($allOtherValidatorsPassed)) 
    {
        // Only now do I do my actual check...
        if (empty($creditCardDetails)) form_set_error('myfield', 
            t('Invalid credit card details entered. Please try again.') 
        );
    }
}
```